# android google map questions

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

1. i'm trying to build a basic layout for each activity. the layout have an action bar and a footer.
   i have no problem to show the footer in a regular activity, but the MapView activity doesn't show my footer although i'm adding it to the xml:

   ```
   <include layout="@layout/actionbar"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   </include>


   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/mapView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:clickable="true" 
   android:enabled="true"   
   android:apiKey="@string/mapAppId" />

   <include layout="@layout/footer"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   </include>
   ```
2. is there a way to load my markers in the MapView after the map has finished loading ? now sometimes my markers are showed before the map done loading..

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the error in may map

 this is the correct code:

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"   
android:clickable="true" 
android:enabled="true"   
android:apiKey="@string/mapAppId" />

<include layout="@layout/footer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </include>
```

pay attention the android:layout_height and android:layout_weight in the map.

i still don't really know how to check if the map is already loaded before showing the markers

Answer (score 1):

```
<include layout="@layout/actionbar"
android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</include>


<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout"
android:layout_above="@+id/footerlayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true" 
android:enabled="true"   
android:apiKey="@string/mapAppId" />

<include layout="@layout/footer"
    android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</include>
```

Comment: no i found it the problem is that android:layout_height="fill_parent"
in the map. is there a way i can tell him to leave room for my footer ??